# Access to CreateView form modal on every page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, create-view

I'm wondering, is it possible to create modal that include `CreateView` form and have access to it on every page in `django`, on every view?

So far I have a `CreateView` in my `views.py`:

```
class ScenarioCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Scenario
    fields = ['title', 'area', 'author']
```

`urls.py`

```
path('scenario/new/', ScenarioCreateView.as_view(), name='scenario-create'),
```

and modal in `base.html` (form is in `scenario_form.html`):

```
<li><a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></li>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal" method="post" action="/scenario/new/">
    <div class="modal-content">
        {% block new %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's working now only from `/scenario/new/`, of course.
I should probably change the path in `urls.py`, right?
Could you help me?

Comment: `form is in scenario_form.html` → What does that mean?

Comment: so, what is your question? all you left to do is use [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag to include content of another html file (in your case, i guess, it is `scenario_form.html`) to your `new` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to **include** your django form in *all* the views so that you can display that on every html template.

To achieve this, you can **register a custom context processor**, and send the form as a context variable to all them templates. Basically, you just need a function that return a dictionary holding your form as the value ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)):

```
from .forms import ScenarioForm  # <-- change it based on your form name

def include_modal_context_processor(request):
    return {'my_form': ScenarioForm(request.POST or None)}
```

(don't forget to register it in the `settings.py`)

and in the template (`base.html`):

```
<li><a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></li>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal" method="post" action="{% url 'scenario-create' %}">
    <div class="modal-content">
        {{ my_form }}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use *named urls* (instead of hard-coding them) as in `{% url 'scenario-create' %}` for the `action`.

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is working! But I have an another question - where can I add function to save my form: ```if newScenario.is_valid():instance.save()```? In ```context_processors.py``` or create new def in ```views.py``` eg. ```def base(request):``` and put form to context? Because now when submit I have only ```"GET /?csrfmiddlewaretoken...``` but no save to database.

Comment: Glad to help :) Your `CreateView` should handle the saving if you send it a `POST` request. Simply add `action="POST"` in your form tag and everything should work fine.

Comment: I added ```action="POST"``` to my form tag in ```base.html``` template and now I have "Page not found (404)" with Request URL after submit. In ```view.py``` Maybe I should add something to ```urls.py```?

Comment: Sorry! sorry! It should be `method="POST" action="{% url 'scenario-create' %}"`

Comment: Basically, what it does is to send a `POST` (method) request to your `scenario/new/` (action); and the `CreateView` will handle the creation new objects.